# Monit, checking URL with basic Auth but username has @ in it

Tags: monit

Monit gives me a syntax error when the username contains an `@`, which would be quite common.  For example, `user@gmail.com` below:

```sh
check host somesite with address monitoring.somesite.com
    if failed url https://user@gmail.com:password@monitoring.somesite.com/
    [...]
```

Doesn't seem to be anything mentioned in [the documenation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Basic-Authentication).

What is the correct method to include special characters in the username?

Comment: `user%40gmail.com` might work.

Answer (score 4):

Monit cannot parse `%40` to `@` But it supports HTTP headers

For example the URL:

```
https://user@mail.com:password@monit.test.basic
```

should be converted to

```sh
Authorization: Basic dXNlckBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

For example:

```sh
check host BasicAuth with address monit.test.basic
    if failed
        port 443
        with protocol https method GET
        with http headers [Authorization: Basic dXNlckBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA==]
    then alert
    else if succeeded then alert
```

Document: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#HTTP

Comment: You can use this website for generating the Basic Auth header. When I used it, it was using Javascript for calculating the string and did not send anything to internet. https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/

Comment: You could also simply go to the network tab in your browser dev tools and take this header from the request headers. Thanks for this answer BTW